# How to place a \figure*\minipage\eqnarray at the bottom of the SAME PAGE

Tags: latex, figure

I have a big equation that must be placed at the bottom of the page in a two columns paper. The call of the equation is at the end of the first column of a given page, but no matter what place holder I set([h!],[ht],etc), the equation goes to the next page. When I use [H] the equation dont even appear in the document.

I am using...

\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
...
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
...

The rotational torque that each motor generates is based on the signal compositions with the servomotor tilting angles. Thus, considering $ \dl = l \frac {\sqrt {2}} {2} $ and the right hand rule, resultant propulsion forces and torques on the $ \Fb $ are presented in Equation (\ref{eq1:gen_forces_torquesa}), suppressing the term $ (t) $:

```
\begin{figure*}[h!]
    \begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
        \begin{eqnarray} \label{eq1:gen_forces_torquesa}
        \bm{\tau^b_p} &=& 
        \left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
        X_{p}^{b} & Y_{p}^{b} & Z_{p}^{b} & L_{p}^{b} & M_{p}^{b} & N_{p}^{b}
        \end{array}
        \right)^T = \nonumber \\
        &=&
        \left(\begin{array}{c}
        k_1\delta_1s(\gamma_1) + k_1\delta_2s(\gamma_2) + k_1\delta_3s(\gamma_3) + k_1\delta_4s(\gamma_4)   \\
        0               \\
        -k_1\delta_1c(\gamma_1) - k_1\delta_2c(\gamma_2) - k_1\delta_3c(\gamma_3) - k_1\delta_4c(\gamma_4)   \\
        (-k_1\dl c(\gamma_1) - k_2s(\gamma_1))\delta_1 + (k_1\dl c(\gamma_2) - k_2s(\gamma_2))\delta_2 + (k_1\dl c(\gamma_3) + k_2s(\gamma_3))\delta_3 + (-k_1\dl c(\gamma_4) +   k_2s(\gamma_4))\delta_4                    \\ 
        A_2             \\
        A_3 
        \end{array}
        \right) \nonumber \\ 
        \end{eqnarray}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

Answer (score 0):

It always helps to have a complete minimal example.

It might be worth trying `[b]` instead. Perhaps also try inserting `\newpage` after the figure.